# Import DXF/DWG in QGIS not at correct location

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dxf, dwg

I have multiple DXF files in CRS EPSG 3857. I would like to import this data into QGIS and convert it into another CRS (EPSG 28992). I've tried importing the DXF file both through the built-in DXF/DWG importer and the AnotherDXF Importer plugin. I'm able to import the data (with the correct CRS), but when I reproject the layer, it stays at the same location (very very far from where it should be). It seems as if there is no location data included in the file? I've also tried converting the DXF into a DWG first (also older versions of DWG).
Does anyone know how I can solve this? The DXF is exported from another software package (Helioscope, if that helps) and I cannot change anything in the export settings.

Comment: I've never seen a DXF carry coordinate system information. Don't "change" the coordinate system--re-project instead.

Comment: Ask whoever created the DXF/DWG?

Comment: Please upload a DXF to test